# How to recover files from a corrupted recycle bin without 3rd party software?

Tags: windows, windows-10, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, recycle-bin

Somebody asked me for help with recovering data from a drive. I'm not exactly sure what happened to it, but the person I got it from told me that the only thing they did was running file system error check from `Properties > Tools`.

The first issue was that I couldn't even access the drive, but I fixed it by changing the owner of the drive (with child objects option checked) to the user on this PC. After this I could open the drive, but many files, that were supposed to be there, were missing. When I click on the Recycle Bin it says that it's corrupted, but when I do `Win+R` and type `H:\$Recycle.Bin`, it says it's empty.

Is it possible, that some of the files are in the Recycle Bin, but aren't visible? If yes, how can I recover them without using 3rd party software?

Comment: You probably made any file recovery impossible by changing the permissions on the disk the way you did.

Comment: @Ramhound Any reason for that? I couldn't access the files anyway.

Comment: https://www.diskgenius.com/how-to/recycle-bin-corrupted.php

Answer (score 0):

The disk is probably corrupted. I guess that the person that ran the
disk scan tool had elected to fix errors, the equivalent of `chkdsk /f`.
This can further destroy a disk that is already corrupted.

I do not believe that the missing files are in the Recycle Bin,
they are more likely lost and may possibly be recovered by specialized tools.

Do NOT modify anything on the disk. If this is the boot disk, take it
out of the computer and put it inside another computer for recovery.
Recover the files to a different disk.

For finding recovery tools, see the article
[Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm).